# Does a group of order 24 have a sylow 11 subgroup

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I am going through *Algebra In Action* by Shahriari and on page 147 it says

> Definition 7.8 (Sylow subgroups). Let G be a finite group with |G| = $p^a$m, where
> $p \nmid m$, and $a$ is a non-negative integer. A subgroup $P \le G$ with $|P| = p^a$ is called
> a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.
> The set of all Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ is denoted by $\operatorname{Syl}_p(G)$.

> Example 7.9. If $G$ is a group of order $24$, then a subgroup of order $3$ would be
> one of its Sylow $3$-subgroups and a subgroup of order $8$ would be one of its Sylow
> $2$-subgroups. The identity subgroup would be its Sylow $5$-subgroup as well as its
> Sylow $11$-subgroup. While we know that $G$ has the identity subgroup, we need
> Sylow’s theorem to know that $G$ actually must have a subgroup of order $3$ and a
> subgroup of order $8$.

Why is the identity subgroup a $5$-subgroup and an $11$-subgroup??!!

EDIT $5^0 = \{$identity of $G\}$ is considered a sylow 5 group by this definition.

Comment: Because the highest power of $5$ that divides $24$ is $5^0$, so the $5$-Sylow subgroup has order $5^0$. Similar with $11$.

Comment: P.S. You seem to be missing the assumption that $\gcd(p,m)=1$ in the definition of Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Its in there I just copied the quote in incorrectly. My issue was that i kept reading "non negative integer" and thinking it meant positive integer ugh! Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Note: I have formatted the post and also added the missing $\nmid$, so that it now reads "$p \nmid m$" instead of "$p \,\, m$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$5$ and $11$ do not divide $24$, i.e. their highest powers which divide $24$ are $5^0$ and $11^0$. So the corresponding Sylow sub-groups have $5^0 = 11^0 = 1$ element. What's a subgroup with just one element? The identity subgroup!

Note that in the definition, $\alpha \ge 0$ and not just $\alpha > 0$. So, $\alpha = 0$ is perfectly okay to consider.